# Ubuntu 18.04 lts settings dont see headphone microphone

Tags: 18.04, microphone, headphones

I have Lenovo T420 thinkpad, Ubuntu 18.04 lts and Bluetooth headphones Philips tah4205 .
When I use command to show devices:

```
pcmd list-cards
    index: 1
name: <bluez_card.98_D3_31_05_B8_33>
driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
owner module: 28
properties:
    device.description = "Philips TAH4205"
    device.string = "98:D3:31:05:B8:33"
    device.api = "bluez"
    device.class = "sound"
    device.bus = "bluetooth"
    device.form_factor = "headset"
    bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_98_D3_31_05_B8_33"
    bluez.class = "0x240404"
    bluez.alias = "Philips TAH4205"
    device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
    device.intended_roles = "phone"
profiles:
    a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: yes)
    headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: no)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
active profile: <a2dp_sink>
sinks:
    bluez_sink.98_D3_31_05_B8_33.a2dp_sink/#1: Philips TAH4205
sources:
    bluez_sink.98_D3_31_05_B8_33.a2dp_sink.monitor/#2: Monitor of Philips TAH4205
ports:
    headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            
    headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
```

last line show that is not available

```
headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
```

I tried things like PulseAudio and PulseAudio see them but choosing them and nothing happens or commands like:

```
pacmd set-source-port 1 analog-input-headset-mic
```

but get

```
No source found by this name or index.
```

Is there any hope I can make headphone microphone work on ubuntu? Output works fine

when I go https://www.onlinemictest.com/ I got:
Microphone not authorized. Please check your media permissions settings.

```
 pacmd list | grep "active port"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
    active port: <headset-output>
    active port: <analog-input-internal-mic>
```

so headset input is not active port

Comment: Do you mean version 18 or 18.04 or 18.10 they are all different.

Comment: You also never mentioned they are Bluetooth I only found that out by looking up the model info you gave. Please edit the question and give the missing information thanks.

Comment: I think I mentioned version 18.04 in the title but forgot about bluetooth. Edited. Do you know anything that can help?

Answer (score 0):

It s a well known limitation of PulseAudio in ubuntu18 (same behavior with logitech H800):

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/1181
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/94

A workaround is called "oFono".